# SIGABRT terminating an app due to uncaught exception

Tags: ios, json, uitableview, nsdata

I'm trying to retrieve data from web service and then filter the data and store it in another array based on a value. However, I get the following error whenever I try to filter it:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary Month]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x174079640'

This is my code:

```
- (void)getDataHTTPClient:(Client *)client didUpdateWithData:(id)data
{
    [self.view setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

    if (isPullRefresh)
    {
        isPullRefresh = NO;
        [datasource removeAllObjects];
        [self.pullToRefreshView finishLoading];
    }

    NSMutableArray *array = (NSMutableArray *)data;
    if (![array count])
    {
        isNewsEnded = YES;
        [self.tableView reloadData];
        return;
    }
    [hud hide:YES];

    [datasource addObjectsFromArray:(NSMutableArray *) data];
    NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
    NSCalendar* calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents* components = [calendar         components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:currentDate];
    monthInt= [components month];
    NSLog(@"month %li", monthInt);
    NSLog(@"month after deduction %li", monthInt-1);

    monthString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%zd",monthInt];

    for (EventsBean *item in datasource)
    {
        if([item.Month isEqualToString:monthString])
        {
            [filteredArray addObject:item];
        }
    }
    [self.tableView reloadData];

    if ([datasource count])
    {
        [self displayNoRecordMSG:NO];
    }
    else
    {
        [self displayNoRecordMSG:YES];
    }
}
```

the error shows on this line

```
 if([item.Month isEqualToString:monthString])
{
    [filteredArray addObject:item];
}
```

Comment: Please log the value of `data` and `datasource`. You are getting wrong type of item.

Comment: What is the content of `datasource` array and how it is populated ?

Comment: `item` appears to be an NSDictionary - maybe you want `item[@"month"]`?

Comment: datasource is a mutablearray that contains EventsBean objects. it is populated from the webserivce.

Comment: to save this issue can you provide log of the bellow line

Comment: id dataResponse = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
if ([dataResponse isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
        NSDictionary *responseDic = (NSDictionary*)dataResponse;
        NSLog(@"responseDic:%@",responseDic);
    }else{
         NSLog(@"dataResponse:%@",dataResponse);
    }

Comment: @jamil65able i get an error used type NSDictionary where arithmetic or pointer type is needed

Comment: The code @jamil65able provided is missing an asterisk when he declared the NSDictionary variable, should be `NSDictionary *responseDic = (NSDictionary *)dataResponse;`. In case you are wondering.

Comment: i just copy and paste but this is missing not by me, perhaps the technical problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data you received over the network will most likely not be an instance of `EventsBean` class. From the error log, it looks like it is actually a `NSDictionary` object. I'm guessing it is already parsed from a JSON string for you. So I would probably try to access the month property by doing `item[@"Month"]` instead.

Comment: its not a dictionary. doesnt allow me to use item[@"month"]

Comment: i can access the values in my table view using `EventsBean *bean = [[EventsBean alloc] initWithDictionary:[filteredArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
`

Comment: What! You do realise that implies you have `NSDictionary` objects in your filtered list, as well as your datasource, right? In the case you can only access the data through `EventsBean` class, why not do `[[EventsBean alloc] initWithDictionary:item].Month`?

Answer (score 1):

```
 for (EventsBean *item in datasource)
```

Here datasource contains objects of NSDictionaries and not objects of EventBeans.

Either you need to parse that dictionary and create object of EventsBean

Or

You need to do something like this

```
if([[item objectForKey:@"Month"] isEqualToString:monthString])
```

Comment: its not a dictionary, doesn't allow me to use objectforkey

Comment: i can access the values in my table view using `EventsBean *bean = [[EventsBean alloc] initWithDictionary:[filteredArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
`

Comment: Than that's the right thing to do... just create the object first and than compare the Month in the code

Comment: sorry here i meant `datasource` instead of `filteredarray`

Comment: Yes you need to do the same thing you need to create the object of EventsBean first from datasource and than use the Month property rather than directly accessing item.Month